# how to do this style slide navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

eg: the main navigation is "one","two","three","four".
the child navigation is "welcome to our site" this navigation under the main nav "one".
the "two1","two2","two3","two4" belongs two,
the "three1","three2 belogs to main nav "three"

now, i want to get when the mouse hover on one, the  "welcome to our site" shows in a blcok.the block only shows the "one" child nav. when hover on the two, the  "two1","two2","two3","two4" shows in the same block.the block only shows the "two" child nav
then hover on the "three". the same as the above.

could i use the jquery or javascript to get this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use javascript; here is one example [dropdown menu](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/simple_drop_down_menu/)

Answer (score -1):

don't know if is understand you right, but this sound like you wan't a simple dropdown-menu, wich is easily possible with pure css. asking [google](http://www.google.de/#q=pure+css+navigation), it just takes 10 seconds to find http://css-dropdownmenu.com wich looks very good.

if i missunderstood the question, please try to be more accurate. have you seen this kind of navigation an another site? if so, could you please post a link?

Comment: http://www.net.cn/  (the red part on the top under the logo. there are 6 navigation.when you mouse hover the one whihc in it. the child nav will show.when mouse.it disappers.